# Making an ODBC connection through System DSN set up under Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an ODBC connection in Java through Windows ODBC Manager.  I have managed to read the registry to get a listing of System DSNs and once a selection is made by the user I read the "HostMachine" parameter in the registry associated with the selected SystemDSN and from there I want to make that ODBC connection.  I have tried the DriverManager getConnection method but it doesn't seem to work!  Any ideas PLZ??!

Please note that I want to access the servers through their associated IP addresses and less likely urls, hence (HostMachine)!

Also each of these System DSNs are associated with a driver that would need to be used to connect its related data source!

```
private static Connection getConnection(String address, String username, String password) throws Exception {
    String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:" + address;
    Class.forName(driver);
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
}
```

I'm getting the following exception!

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Thanks Dan, I did as you said but now I'm getting this exception, what do you think??!

```
java.sql.SQLException: General error
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
```

Here's the complete stack trace!  Any ideas please??!

```
java.sql.SQLException: General error
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do this, get a JDBC-ODBC bridge and choose a JDBC URL that fits according to that particular bridge driver's documentation. Sun [made one](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/bridge.doc.html) a while back, but I don't know if it's supported any more.

If you do this, you don't need the driver specific details from ODBC, just use the named data source directly.

But I would *strongly* suggest you not do this. Get the real JDBC driver(s) for the database(s) you need and give your program some way of getting the relevant JDBC connection details for these, and leave ODBC out of the picture.

Comment: In this scenario I'd have to perform using this routine! Do what happens to the dll driver already associated with the System DSN??!  Does jdbc-odbc driver take care of that as well??!

Comment: I've updated my question with the exception I'm getting!  Any ideas??!

Comment: Don't pass the "address" as part of the JDBC URL. Pass the actual _name_ of the System DSN.

Comment: Thanks Dan, it seems to be doing somethings now!  However, I'm getting another exception which I posted on the question area!

Comment: I don't really know. I'd need some more details about the specific JDBC call you are making and the specific values you're passing to it. If you add some more detail to your question - including a full stack trace of that exception - I or someone else might be able to help.

Comment: Also, if you get completely stuck, turn on ODBC tracing in the ODBC Administrator and look at the log it produces.

Comment: Hi Dan, Here's the stack trace!  Do you have any idea what's causing this issue??! It's something about an unknown source!

Comment: If I send you the ODBC tracing, would you be able to interpret this to me??!  I have ran it but I have difficulty understanding what's causing the issue!

Comment: Don't send it to me, but you can put it in a pastebin and link it from your question.